# Copy folders and files with saving structure with GulpJS

Tags: node.js, gulp

I need to copy some folders with files from `src` folder to `public`.

My task:

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    return gulp
           .src([
                './src/somejson.json',
                './src/sometext.txt',
                './src/fonts/**/*',
                './src/sounds/**/*'
                ], { base: './src' })

           .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'))
});
```

This is placing `sometext.txt` and `somejson.json` in `public` folder, but this is placing folders `fonts` and `sounds` in `public` folder WITHOUT files inside.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the beginning of the path relative,

```
gulp.src([
 './src/somejson.json',
 './src/sometext.txt',
 './src/fonts/**/*',
 './src/sounds/**/*'
])
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
```